# Running a Java Program (which uses HDFS JAVA API) outside $HADOOP_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I have a simple Java program which simply reads and writes some text to a file on HDFS. I run it using **hadoop HDFSReadWrite text**.

I want to run it from eclipse or just like any other java program and still be able to use the HDFS outside the Hadoop environment. Is there a way to do that? I need it real bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run a mapreduce job in Eclipse. It's shouldn't be much different from a HDFS program.

- Start the namenode and the datanode from the command prompt.
- Create a Java Project in Eclipse.
- Include the common, hdfs and the required jar files.
- Include the HDFSReadWrite.java file in the project.
- Pass the following parameters to the java program.
  "-- config ConfigurationDirectory text"
- Execute the HDFSReadWrite

Instead of including the jar files the corresponding Eclipse projects can be included in the build path or the src jar files attached for debugging purpose.

Instead of a creating a Java project, copy the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar file in the eclipse plugin folder and create a 'Map/Reduce Project'. Then the required jar files are included automatically.

The different command options are mentioned in the below URL

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/commands_manual.html